# Get on-click URL

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer, url, magento-community, geturl

I have site using Magento 1.7, and have as a first page a login that is mandatory.

I implemented the mandatory login via an observer, that is in charge of only allowing acces to the login page while the user is not logged in.

My code for the Observer is below:

```
public function checkForLogin(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
  $allow = array('customer_account_login',
   'customer_account_createpost',
    'customer_account_create',
    'customer_account_forgotpassword',
    'customer_account_resetpassword',
    'customer_account_loginpost',
    'customer_account_forgotpasswordpost',
    'customer_account_resetpasswordpost');

  $currentURL = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
  $url = Mage::getSingleton('core/url')->parseUrl($currentUrl);
  $path = $url->getPath();
  $contactPaths = array('/mystore/index.php/es/contacts/');

   //Check if any customer is logged in or not, or if he is clicking the contacts page
   if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() && !in_array(strtolower($observer->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName()),$allow) && !in_array($path,$contactPaths)) 
    {
    Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login'))->sendResponse();
    //echo var_dump($observer->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName());
    exit;
   }
 }
}
```

The problem is that I want to allow the user to access the contacts page, even if he/she is not logged in. And that's why I included the use of `getCurrentURL()`, `getPath()`, and added a condition inside the `if()`.

But I still can't access the contact pages. I am not sure of the behavior of `getCurrentUrl()`. What I need to get is the URL of the button that the user just clicked on; but maybe `getCurrentUrl()` just returns the URL of the current page, as its name suggests.

Is there any method available to get the URL of a clicked button? Or maybe I am missing something?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try using the core way like $_SERVER to get the URL and for redirect try to use this Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to allow access to contact us page just add `contacts_index_index` in `$allow` array and undo the condition for `$contactPaths`

if you want to add any other url in the array you can get the Full action name by calling this code on that page

```
echo Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName()
```

Comment: Perfect, so simple and it works. Thanks. Where can I find a list with all the possibilities, in case I need again? This 'contacts_index_index' is an Action Name right?

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with this :

```
<?
public function checkForLogin(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
  $allow = array('customer_account_login',
   'customer_account_createpost',
    'customer_account_create',
    'customer_account_forgotpassword',
    'customer_account_resetpassword',
    'customer_account_loginpost',
    'customer_account_forgotpasswordpost',
    'customer_account_resetpasswordpost');

  $currentURL = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
  $path = explode('/',$currentURL);
  //Check if any customer is logged in or not, or if he is clicking the contacts page
   if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() && !in_array(strtolower($observer->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName()),$allow) && !in_array('contacts',$path)) 
    {
    Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login'))->sendResponse();
    //echo var_dump($observer->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName());
    exit;
   }
 }
}
```

Here is good module for this [get here.](https://github.com/jreinke/magento-require-login)